# How to navigate from a page back to the MainWindow?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, navigation

I'm currently building a WPF application and I'm having trouble navigating back to the MainWindow from another page (compiledpage).

I've able to navigate back to previous pages but not the MainWindow itself.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs** (Window)

```
private void startTroubleshootButton_Clicknew(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // instantiate the Q1 page and assign it to "pg1" variable
    Q1 pg1 = new Q1();

    // Sets the current content control view to Q1 page
    this.Content = pg1;
}
```

**Q1.xaml.cs** (page)

```
private void naviQ2ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // instantiate mainwindow and store it in the window variable
    var window = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;

    // instantiate Q2 page and pass the string variable "sb" as arguments to Q2 page/class
    Q2 pg2 = new Q2(sb.ToString());

    // set the current content control to Q2 page
    window.Content = pg2;
}
```

**Q2.xaml.cs** (page)

```
private void compileButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // instantiate mainwindow and store it in the window variable
    var window = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;

    // instantiate  compiledpage and pass the string variable "sb" and valueFromQ1 as arguments to compiledpage/class
    Compiledpage pg3 = new Compiledpage(sb.ToString(), valueFromQ1); 

    // Show compiledpage in the current window
    window.Content = pg3;
}
```

**compiledpage.xaml.cs** (page)

```
private void backButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     MainWindow pg = new MainWindow();
     var window = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
     window.Content = pg;  //<- this doesn't work
}
```

The back button click of compiledpage was supposed to go back to the MainWindow window but it doesn't seem to work. Is there a better way to code this? Thanks.

Comment: Your question doesn't makes sense, a window cannot be a page. Your window hosts a page that you consider as the main page, what's entirely different. Also, edit your question with a more complete example as there are different approaches in implementing navigation-based WPF apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a Frame control to your MainWindow and use that frame to change the window content. See this example.

MainWindow.xaml

```xml
<Grid Background="#eeeeee">
    <Frame 
        Name="MainFrame"
        Margin="16"
        Background="White"
        NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"/>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```cs
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Application.Current.MainWindow = this;
        Loaded += OnMainWindowLoaded;
    }

    private void OnMainWindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ChangeView(new Page1());
    }

    public void ChangeView(Page view)
    {
        MainFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(view);
    }
}
```

Page1.xaml

```xml
<StackPanel>
    <Label 
        Foreground="YellowGreen" 
        Content="Page 1 Content"
        FontSize="32"/>
    <Button 
        Content="Go to Page2"
        Margin="8"
        Click="OnGoToPage2ButtonClicked"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Page1.xaml.cs

```cs
public partial class Page1
{
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnGoToPage2ButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var mainWindow = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
        mainWindow?.ChangeView(new Page2());
    }
}
```

---

Page2.xaml

```xml
<StackPanel>
    <Label 
        Foreground="YellowGreen" 
        Content="Page 2 Content"
        FontSize="32"/>
    <Button 
        Content="Go to Page3"
        Margin="8"
        Click="OnGoToPage3ButtonClicked"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Page2.xaml.cs

```cs
public partial class Page2
{
    public Page2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnGoToPage3ButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var mainWindow = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
        mainWindow?.ChangeView(new Page3());
    }
}
```

---

Page3.xaml

```xml
<StackPanel>
    <Label 
        Foreground="BlueViolet" 
        Content="Page 3 Content"
        FontSize="32"/>
    <Button 
        Content="Back to Page1"
        Margin="8"
        Click="OnBackToPage1ButtonClicked"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Page3.xaml.cs

```cs
public partial class Page3
{
    public Page3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnBackToPage1ButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var mainWindow = (MainWindow) Application.Current.MainWindow;
        mainWindow?.ChangeView(new Page1());
    }
}
```

[Example full code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0ghm4j0vdux8py8/Q_58470318.rar?dl=0)

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use ContentControl for your solution.
Create multiple views (user control) and pass this instance to the ContentControl.Content property.

```
...
<ContentControl x:Name="navigatedRegion"/>
...
```

When you need to navigate your views do it:

```
public void NavigateToA()
{
    var viewA = new ViewA();
    navigatedRegion.Content = viewA;
}
```

viewA is instance of custom user control.